# add checked items in CheckedListBox to difrent fields in sql vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm filling a CheckBoxList with Company names (this works fine)

```
'Fill CheckBoxList'
Try
    con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CName FROM Company ORDER BY CName ASC"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Do While dr.Read = True
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
    Loop
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Try
```

Now I need to INSERT the checked names into a table with each company name in it's own Field

Here I'm stuck...

When I click the button to show the record, I want the CheckBoxList to select the company names that are in the fields (the CheckBoxList has Company1 till Company10, if I select Company2, Company4, Company8 and Company10 - when I pull the record these Companies will be checked)

Maybe a separate field for each Company is not necessary, I'm opened for ideas...

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

I fount this somewhere, but it inserts the CheckedItems in separate rows

```
    Dim db As String = Datasource & filename & line & param
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(db)
        con.Open()
        Dim checkedItem As Object
        For Each checkedItem In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
            cmd = con.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Mall (Company) VALUES ('" & checkedItem & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        con.Close()
    End Using
```

Can this be modified to do what I need ?

Comment: If you have to number your fields, its a sign of a bad/wrong db model.

Comment: @Plutonix please elaborate

Comment: Think about what the SQL would look like to find a company: (using parameters of course). `...WHERE Company1 = @c OR Company2 = @c OR Company3 = @c OR ...`  Its even worse with code trying to word with a DataTable.  Your db design is missing a relation/rule *a foo can be one or many Companies*

Answer (score 0):

The following loaded department names and id from a SQL-Server database table into a CheckedListBox on form load. A button click gets checked department names and passes them to a procedure to insert into say another table or whatever you want to do.

DisplayMember is taken from ToString in Department class.

Class to handle loading and working with data

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Operations
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Replace with your SQL Server name
    ''' </summary>
    Private Server As String = "KARENS-PC"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Targeted database
    ''' </summary>
    Private Catalog As String = "ForumExamples"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Connection string for connecting to the database
    ''' </summary>
    Private ConnectionString As String = ""
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Setup the connection string
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        ConnectionString = $"Data Source={Server};Initial Catalog={Catalog};" &
            "Integrated Security=True"
    End Sub
    Public Function GetDepartments() As List(Of Department)
        Dim departments As New List(Of Department)

        Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id,Name FROM Departments"

                cn.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    departments.Add(New Department With
                                    {
                                        .Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                        .Name = reader.GetString(1)
                                    })
                End While

            End Using
        End Using
        Return departments
    End Function
    Public Sub InsertDepartments(sender As List(Of Department))
        Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection With
            {
                .ConnectionString = ConnectionString
            }
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand With
                {
                    .Connection = cn, .CommandText = "Your SQL INSERT statement"
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With
                                   {
                                    .ParameterName = "@Name", .DbType = DbType.String
                                   })
                cn.Open()
                For Each dept As Department In sender
                    cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = dept.Name
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Console.WriteLine(dept.Name)
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Department
    Property Id As Integer
    Property Name As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Form code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim departments As New List(Of Department)
        CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of Department).ToList.ForEach(
            Sub(d)
                departments.Add(d)
            End Sub)
        ops.InsertDepartments(departments)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No departments selected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have a server, I'm using SQLite.net. How do I change that?

Comment: This is why it's good to indicate up front the database used. So, I use a connection and command object which SQLLite.net has too, you need to switch in my example for SqlClient to SQLLite e.g. rather then SqlConenction use SQLiteConnection etc.